# cant view C structures from an assembly program?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, struct, system-calls

I'm trying to read the output of `sysinfo` system call from an assembly program but it seems that the system call leaves the `sysinfo` struct unchanged

```
.section .data
 result:
    uptime:
        .quad 00
    loads:
        .quad 00
    total_ram:
        .quad 00
    free_ram:
        .quad 00
    shared_ram:
        .quad 00, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

.section .bss
.section .text
.globl main
main:
    nop
    movq $99, %rax
    leaq result(%rip), %rdi
    syscall
    nop
```

strace shows that sysinfo is called correctly but using gdb to view the result after the `syscall` shows that all are still unchanged(0). Also `rax` is 0 which means that `syscall` is called successfully. So why did `syscall` didnt modify the `result` struct although it works normally using C so why did this happen.

/********************* Debugging part *************************/

gdb at last `nop` instruction (`(gdb) x/9dg &result`:

```
0x7ffff7faad80 <result>:        0       0
0x7ffff7faad90 <result+16>:     0       0
0x7ffff7faada0 <result+32>:     0       0
0x7ffff7faadb0 <result+48>:     0       0
0x7ffff7faadc0 <result+64>:     0
```

man page of `sysinfo` (`man 2 sysinfo`):

```
  int sysinfo(struct sysinfo *info);
struct sysinfo {
               long uptime;             /* Seconds since boot */
               unsigned long loads[3];  /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */
               unsigned long totalram;  /* Total usable main memory size */
               unsigned long freeram;   /* Available memory size */
               unsigned long sharedram; /* Amount of shared memory */
               unsigned long bufferram; /* Memory used by buffers */
               unsigned long totalswap; /* Total swap space size */
               unsigned long freeswap;  /* Swap space still available */
               unsigned short procs;    /* Number of current processes */
               char _f[22];             /* Pads structure to 64 bytes */
           };
```

running `strace ./sysinfo` shows this line

```
sysinfo({uptime=21623, loads=[134496, 128288, 129056], totalram=6125535232, freeram=231415808, sharedram=593993728, bufferram=306745344, totalswap=2147479552, freeswap=2056269824, procs=887, totalhigh=0, freehigh=0, mem_unit=1}) = 0
```

Comment: I believe your structure is incorrect.  Please cross-check with the manual.

Comment: Works fine here (I see stuff changing, I did not check your struct layout). You likely examined it wrong. [edit] your question with gdb output.

Comment: @Jester gonna edit the question with ```gdb``` output and man page of the struct

Comment: @Jester edited the question with debugging info .

Comment: gdb is picking up the wrong `result` symbol. Use `x/9dg $rdi`.

Comment: @Jester you are right but what is happening exactly?

Comment: `loads` is 3 quads.

Comment: Are you sure that `leaq result(%rip), %rdi` gives the correct address in rdi?

Comment: `.globl result` might help get debug symbols to resolve `result` to yours instead of maybe one in libc (it looks like).  @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: the assembler will definitely resolve `result` to the symbol of that name defined in the same file.  It's only once you're in GDB and symbols from the executable and libc are all available (with non-global symbols equivalent to C `static`) that there's any ambiguity.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate of [gdb behaves differently for symbols in the .bss, vs. symbols in .data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39224443) - the same problem with glibc defining a non-global `buf` symbol.  My answer there shows how to sort out what's going on.

Comment: @PeterCordes what I meant is: doesn't `leaq result(%rip)...` add %rip and the offset of `result`? And does this sum point to the intended buffer? I am not sure.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Oh, you're concerned about the syntax itself, not which version of `result` it's referencing.  It means result wrt. RIP, like NASM `[rel result]`.  This is an inconsistency in GAS syntax between symbols vs. numeric literals that also exists in GAS .intel_syntax: [How do RIP-relative variable references like "\[RIP + \_a\]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54745872)

Comment: @PeterCordes TY, that's exactly what I meant, and the link you posted did clarify the doubt.