# Assembly, gdb duplicate names

Tags: variables, assembly, gdb, debug-symbols, variable-names

Let's assume we have defined a global non-initialized variable named `f` in C code.
Considering that, we would make label named `f` in the Assembly representation and put it in the `.bss` section.
The problem I've encountered is the following:

- Using `la` works fine, and loads the address of user-defined global variable into some register
- Trying to print, or examine the symbol `f` in gdb returns some object at some address `0x7f7f...` which is not the variable I intended to print
- Using `info variables` I was able to find a `static FILE *f` pointer variable f probably originating from C library that got linked with the source file, and concluded it being what is getting printed in gdb
- I also tried doing `p 'file.s'::f` to print the user-defined variable but had no luck with that either

So my question is how to differentiate between duplicate symbol names while debugging using gdb?

Comment: Did you remember to use `.global f`?

Comment: @NateEldredge, yes the .globl directive was used.

Comment: [gdb behaves differently for symbols in the .bss, vs. symbols in .data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39220351) shows an example of checking their addresses to see which one `f` or `buf` is resolving to, and the addresses of all vars of that name with `info variables` to see which comes from where.  At worst you can just work with the addresses; perhaps with debug metadata like `.type` your `f` could be the one that takes precedence.