# C: Why is this address of the char array 6 bytes?

Tags: c, memory-address

I thought addresses are 4 bytes big, why is this address 6 bytes?

Im compiling with gcc on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 20.04 and I got an x64 processor if this matters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

        char char_array[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        printf("Address of char_array: %p\n", char_array);
}
```

```
$ gcc -g test.c
$ ./a.out
Address of char_array: 0x7ffc0ff83645
```

Comment: Are addresses 4 bytes long on a 64-bit computer?

Comment: 4 bytes is only 32 bits. You're in the 64 bit world now!

Comment: The address is eight bytes (because it's a 64 bit computer/program), but the high two bytes are zeroes, that's all.

Comment: 6 bytes (apparently) due to leading 0 suppression.

Comment: The actual address bus [is 48 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6716946/10077), so I don't think you'll ever see anything in those two high bytes.

Comment: Thank you guys! Sorry for this trivial question

Comment: @FredLarson: Hah - echos of the Motorola 68000, which had a 24-bit address bus.  Enterprising Macintosh programmers would often stuff data into those 8 unused bits to make the most of that precious 128KB of RAM.  Worked great until the 68020 came out, which had a 32-bit address bus and all that code had to be rewritten.

Comment: @FredLarson: What does the physical address on the bus have to do with the virtual address in a process?

Comment: If you want to know how big a pointer is on your computer, just look at `sizeof(void *)`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Well, that's valid. But it does appear that the virtual address space isn't necessarily the full 64 bits either, at least according to this comment on what I linked: "A number of modern x86_64 CPUs support a 48-bit physical address space and a 52-bit virtual address space."

Comment: ... or maybe that comment [got it backwards](https://superuser.com/q/655121/37572).

Comment: @FredLarson: indeed, current x86-64 hardware has 48-bit virtual addresses.  [Why in 64bit the virtual address are 4 bits short (48bit long) compared with the physical address (52 bit long)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46509152) on SO is the same answer.  Linux puts the user-space stack at the top of the lower canonical range of virtual addresses (47 bit), reserving the upper half for kernel virtual addresses.  [Address canonical form and pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38977755)

Comment: @JohnBode: AMD learned from past problems and has the hardware check that addresses are correctly sign-extended 48-bit.  If you want to use the upper 16 bits (or upper 8 with PML5) for other data, you have to redo sign extension before using it as a pointer; the HW won't ignore it.  (e.g. for user-space, but ANDing to zero-extend).  So backwards compat for such programs will just involve having future OSes limit which virtual addresses they allocate for processes with a certain "personality flag" set.  [Address canonical form and pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38977755)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all C pointers are oftentimes either 4-byte (32-bit) or 8-byte (64-bit) but this is not guaranteed and should not be assumed.

Secondly you can’t count the digits in a hexadecimal memory address and assume that the number of digits divided by two is the number of bytes the system uses for a pointer, because leading zeroes are not being printed. For instance if your memory address was `0x00000020` and you passed it to `printf()` with the `%p` specifier, you would get an output of `0x20`.

If you want to know the byte width of a `char*` in your system you should try `printf(“%zd\n”,sizeof(char*));`

Answer (score 0):

The virtual address space on x64 is 48 bits (6 bytes) long.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

%8p  to show all 8 bytes of address.
also

```
fprintf(stdout, "%d  %d", sizeof(char_array), sizeof(&(char_array[0])));
```

The second use of sizeof() depends on your compiler...

Comment: Note that you should be using the `%zu` format specifier for `size_t` types (such as returned by the `sizeof` operator) and `%08p` to display leading zeros in a pointer (`%8p` will pad the length of the output to 8 characters by using spaces).